# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 network backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

Can MS SQL 2008 R2 backup database to a file on different network location...I've been unable to set network path for backup to other machine on local network via tasks-backup-destination.add location...

Comment: As a workaround, you can use SQLBackupAndFTP Free edition. It allows you to backup your MS SQL Server 2008 R2 to a network. Here is a short tutorial https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/backup-sql-server-on-the-network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can. We backup to a network location although we have the location mapped to a drive.

It seems you can use a UNC as well though according to this answer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/965cd9c4-f4d5-4492-a202-f09b78d89ed1/how-to-backup-a-database-to-a-network-drive?forum=sqltools.

Have a look at the answer as there's some good considerations on here like if the sql service login has access to the network location.

Comment: We're backing up regularly to a CIFS location (UNC path), it is not a problem. You just need to check that the service account has correct writing permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I shared the Users\Public\Documents folder on my machine, for public access from inside the network domain, and tried backing up to the UNC path:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [HooHah] TO  DISK = N'\\MY_MACHINE\Users\Public\Documents\HooHah.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'HooHah Full Backup 151114', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

It worked fine.  The backup file restored okay to my local machine server instance, which was the ultimate goal.